# How to retrieve realm object from different function? Swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm, uilocalnotification, realm-mobile-platform

I currently have a function that writes a realm object into the database and writes a notification. When the object is written, it is added into a uicollectionview and displayed. The function below adds the object and sets a notification based on a UIDatePicker. That code is not shown since it is a lot that doesn't pertain to the problem:

```
func createTaskWithDate() {
   let task = Task()
 task.name = textField.text!
 //notification code under here
 try! realm.write {
 realm.add(task)
 updateData()
    }
```

I also have another function that responds to an action on a notification set. When the user taps on the notification, they are given the option to "mark as complete". When the user taps "mark as complete", I am trying to retrieve the object from the "createTaskWithDate()" method and delete it from the collection view however I'm unsure on how to retrieve that object from that method:

```
 func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let identifier = response.actionIdentifier
    let request = response.notification.request
    if identifier == "complete" {
        try! realm.write {
            //realm.delete(task object from createTaskWithDate())
        updateData()

        }
    }
    completionHandler()
}
```

How could I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When setting up the notification, you should store the name/primary key of the object the notification is about in your notification request. You can store any information in `UNMutableNotificationContent.userInfo` and access it in `userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:)` by

`let userInfo = response.notification.content.userInfo`.

Then you can retrieve the object from `Realm` with the primary key stored in `userInfo`.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create new element when your User Notification have fired or find element that already exist? If you want to find, you can query that element from data base and than delete it. You can query by date or identifier (you can implement it using User Defaults, by adding identifier field to element and increment it each time when you create new element). 
For UI modification after object manipulation you can use object notifications from Realm. You can read about it [here](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#object-notifications).

Comment: But since every task has a different title, how would I retrieve the right one? Let's say my task name is "buy groceries". In the notification it will say: "reminder: buy groceries". Then if the user taps the mark as complete action it has to delete that specific object from realm.

Comment: As for me, I have used identifier field to determine what element was marked. Identifier is a unique key to specific Notification. And action for this (how I understand, you want user to tap a button at notification to mark this element) by adding UNNotificationAction and check what specific action button user tap. Just rewrite your identifier using and add action to your notification, don't use a title for checking the elements.